# Having some scoping issue with $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, scoping, chart.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var data = [
    {
        value: 30,
        color:"#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Red"
    },
    {
        value: 30,  
        color: "#46BFBD",
        highlight: "#5AD3D1",
        label: "Green"
    },
    {
        value: 30,
        color: "#FDB45C",
        opacity: 30,
        highlight: "#FFC870",
        label: "Yellow"
    }
];


    var ctx = $('#chart-area').get(0).getContext("2d");
    var myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data, {
            responsive : true,
            animateRotate: true,
            animateScale: false,
            percentageInnerCutout: 70,
            animationEasing : "easeInOutQuart"
    });

  function updateData() {
      data.forEach(function(entry) {
          entry.value += 10;
      });
  }

  document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    updateData(); // for demo only
    var index = 0;

    myDoughnut.segments.forEach(function(segment) {
      segment.value = data[index++].value;
    });
      myDoughnut.update();
  };
});
```

Having issues with not reading the "myDoughnut". This is the error provided in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined users.js?body=1:50

However when I test it out on another file and have the script on the bottom of the page without the $(document).ready or window onload it works perfectly.

Comment: here is a fiddlefor the code your provided but no error, can you try to use it to reproduce? http://fiddle.jshell.net/leighking2/nbf2kcde/. Also what line does the error refer to data.forEach or myDoughnut.segments.forEach